# Function scope regarding pointers in C++ (or C)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, scope

I am attempting to write portable code that allows the function to access a variable like an array, even if it is just a single value. The idea behind it is that the code will not make an array of size 1, but I need to be able to loop over all the values in the array if it is an array. Since I can't use `sizeof(foo)` to determine whether the memory is larger than a single instance `sizeof(foo)/sizeof(int)` might work, but it is too cumbersome to include in the main code. Macros wouldn't help because if I used a ternary operator like I'd expect `#define ARRAY_OR_NOT(foo, type) (sizeof(foo)/sizeof(type) > 1) ? (foo) : (&foo)` to return a pointer, in order to access with indexing. This problem is the compiler doesn't like the mixing of types between pointers and non-pointers.

So my second attempt was function overloading.

```
int * convert(int value)
    {return &value;}
int * convert(int * value)
    {return value;}
```

I know that this wouldn't work, because the first function would return the address of the temporary variable copy in that function scope. So my third attempt was

```
int * convert(int * value)
    {return value;}
int * convert(int ** value)
    {return *value;}
```

Every time I would call convert, pass the address of the value: `convert(&foo)`.
This should work, and (I think) it avoids returning a temporary function scope 
address. The result of convert would be accessible with indexing. In a controlled for loop, the code would run smoothly. The program would know how many elements are in value, but it would be faster to run everything inside a for loop than not.

So why does my second block of code produce the "Warning returning temporary scope blahblahblah" warning?

UPDATE: Major XY problem here.

Basically I'm trying to wrap all my code in a loop and access each value in a variable, one value per loop iteration. The system would know how many values are in that variable, but the code base is so large that wrapping everything in an if/else would be slow. So the way to access some value in the for loop with an index would be `int foo = convert(&maybeArray)[counter];` Then I would use foo several times in the for loop. 
For some reason Visual Studio was throwing an error while with the second block of code. Added this to OP.

Another solution would be to make 2 functions with overloaded operators that would basically execute the entire code, without converting each variable, but the code base is very large, and this needs to be as portable as possible. Referencing `convert` would be more future proof I would believe.

Comment: As a note, to determine whether something is an array, a more reliable way is `( (char *)(foo) == (char *)&(foo) )`.

Comment: And can you post the exact code with the warning? I don't any with the second code (compiled as C++). Is this a C or a C++ question?

Comment: There should be no warning for your third attempt/second block. Can you post the actual message and a complete example?

Comment: This seems like The XY Problem. Why are you trying to do this? `allows the function to access a variable like an array` - what do you mean by that? Could you show us an example of how you would call this function?

Comment: XY Problem indeed. Basically I'm trying to wrap all my code in a loop and access each value in a variable, one value per loop iteration. The system would know how many values are in that variable, but the code base is so large that wrapping everything in an if/else would be slow. So the way to access some value in the for loop with an index would be `int foo = convert(&maybeArray)[counter];` For some reason Visual Studio was throwing an error while with the second block of code. Added this to OP.

Comment: Also mafso, why are you typecasting foo to be a string? Wouldn't that just be a glorified strcmp? Also why would that work? If it foo were an array, the left hand would be the address of the first value, and the right side would be the address of foo, which would return false I would think.

Comment: A conversion of a pointer to `char *` yields the address of the lowest-addressed byte. A pointer to the first element of an array and a pointer to the whole array have the same value (but a different type, which is why a cast is needed). `strcmp` is totally different (e.g. it compares contents of arrays, not addresses). The test isn't perfect, btw, the expression is also true for `void *foo = &foo;` (the test is reliable the other way round, if the test is false, `foo` is not an array).

Comment: What's the point in just finding the start of an array? Don't you need the end of the array too? Maybe your question should simply be *"I have many arrays and I wish to loop over every element in these arrays. In the particular case of a non-array variable, I wish to treat it as a single-element array."*

Comment: Are C++11 solutions allowed? Perhaps you could tag this question with `c++03` or `c++11` or even `c++14` as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged this as `C++`, so I'm assuming you are using a C++ compiler.

There's a lot going on in your question, so I'm going to simplify. You want a C++ function `convert(x)` that will:

> 1. if `x` is an array, return the address of the first element
> 2. if `x` is not an array, return `&x`.

(Generally, maybe you need to redesign this whole thing, `convert` seems like a pretty strange function to want).

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
auto convert(  T (&t) [N] ) -> T* {
    return t; // just let pointer decay work for us here
}
template<typename T>
auto convert( T &t) -> T* {
    return &t;
}
```

And, in C++, I would never use `sizeof` with things that <strike>I think</strike> are arrays. This template technique is a safer way to count the number of elements in an array.

Also, do you expect to have arrays of pointers, and to want to treat a single pointer as a single-element-array of pointers? If so, then tread carefully. Something that looks like an array, might actually be a pointer, e.g. arrays in parameter lists `foo(int is_really_a_pointer[5]) { ...}`. See the comment by @MSalters for more. Might be good to use his assert to catch any surprises. If you're just using `int`, then don't use the `typename T` in my templates, just force it to be `int` for clarity.

Finally, maybe instead of turning arrays into pointers, you should ask for a function that turns a non-array into a reference to a single-element array?

***Update*** Here is a [more complete example](http://ideone.com/0A6MUE) showing how to use `convert` and `convert_end` to find the beginning and end of an array to iterate over all the elements in an array; where, of course, a non-array is treated as an array of one element.

Comment: With this pair of functions, it's often beneficial to also have `void convert(T* ) { static_assert(false, "don't pass raw pointers!"); }`. The reason is that inside `void foo(int bar[5])`, the `bar` argument actually is a pointer and not an array.

Comment: @MSalters, I guess it is possible that a developer really does intend a pointer to be treated as a single-element array of pointers. But yes, such an assert would be useful to force the developer to think carefully before using pointers like this.

Comment: Even if you intend to treat a `T*` as a `T[1]`, a two-overload solution can backfire when it treats your pointer as a `T*[1]` (!)

Comment: Nobody intends to treat a `T*` as a `T[1]`. The intention is to treat a `T` (specifically, an lvalue `T`) as a `T[1]`. If somebody has made the mistake of having an array as a parameter, as in your example, then they're screwed anyway! Arrays in params as just too weird. (Taking an array by reference makes more sense in general, and also gives sensible behaviour with respect to this question and this answer)

Answer (score 1):

In C, there exist only pass by value. When you pass a pointer to a function then its address is copied to the function parameter. This simply means that if `p` is a pointer in calling function then a function call

```
int x = 5;
int *p = &x;
int a = foo(p);
```

for function definition

```
int foo(int *p1)
{
    return *p1*2;
}
```

is implies that:

- copy the address `p` points to parameter `p1`, i.e make `p` and `p1` points to the same location.
- any changes to the location pointed by `p1` in function foo is reflected to `*p` because `p` and `p1` is pointing to same location. But, if at any point `p1` points to another location then this does not imply that `p` will point to that location too. `p` and `p1` are two different pointers.

When you you pass a pointer to pointer, as in your last snippet of second block,

```
int * convert(int ** value)
{return *value;}
```

if `*value` changes to points to different location after argument is passed to it, then that pointer whose address is passed will also be updated with this location. In this case no need to return `*value`, but returning do no harm.

Comment: This is basically reaffirming what I knew about function scope and pass by value in C/++. I was pretty sure the second example would've worked, but I was scared by the warning.